# Export users not in an office 365 security group

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, office365

I need to find users that are not in a office 365 security group. I'm not sure how to proceed after getting the list of all the users in the tenant.

This works for pulling a list of users

```
Get-MSOLUser -all | Where-Object { $_.isLicensed -eq "True"} | Select-Object UserPrincipalName | Export-Csv -path .\users.csv
```

I'm not sure where to go from here.
This is something like what I'm looking for.

```
Get-MSOLUser -all | Where-Object { $_.isLicensed -eq "True",-and $_.isNotMemberofGroup "SecurityGroup"} | Select-Object UserPrincipalName | Export-Csv -path .\users.csv
```

Comment: IIRC, the cmdlet doesn't return an object with a group membership property. You're likely to use `Get-MsolGroup` + `Get-MsolGroupMember`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a way of testing this but this should be the logic you should follow with this pre-historic module, first get the list of members of your target group (in this case `ExampleGroup`) and then you can loop over all the users filtering by both conditions:

1. The user has a License
2. The user is not a member of the Target Group

```
$targetGroup = "ExampleGroup"
$groupMembers = Get-MsolGroup $targetGroup | Get-MsolGroupMember

Get-MsolUser -All | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.isLicensed -eq $true -and $_.ObjectId -notin $groupMembers.ObjectId) {
        $_
    }
} | Select-Object UserPrincipalName | Export-Csv -Path .\users.csv
```

Comment: Thanks I was able use this and get the list of users

Comment: @MWolfe60 happy to help, please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

the Cmdlets do not natively provide such features but with PowerShell we can use `Compare-Object` to check differences between two object arrays:

1. Fetch all users: `$allUsers = Get-MSOLUser -all`
2. Fetch members of your group: `$groupMembers = Get-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId <Your-Group-ID>`
3. Compare the two arrays: `Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $groupMembers -DifferenceObject $allUsers -Property ObjectId`
4. Based on your needs you can filter the above based on the `SideIndicator` property
5. Export the results by piping the above with | Export-CsV ...

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get the answer to work for me. Perhaps this works for others.

```
$targetGroup = "ExampleGroup"
$groupMembers = Get-MsolGroupMember -groupobjectid $targetGroup

Get-MsolUser -All | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.isLicensed -eq $true -and $_.ObjectId -notin $groupMembers.ObjectId) {
        $_
    }
} | Select-Object UserPrincipalName | Export-Csv -Path .\users.csv
```